# Relative Clause of Purpose with Quo

Tags: syntax, grammar-identification, neuter

Moreland has this sentence in Relative Clause of Purpose (Unit 14):

> Properatis quo celerius adveniatis.

which it translates as:

> You hasten by which you may arrive more quickly.

The adjective 'celerius' here is in the accusative but why is it in the neuter?

Answer (score 7):

Celerius is the comparative adverb of *celer,-is,-e* and modifies the subjunctive verb *adveniatis*.